# Converting PNG file to bitmap array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, image, png, pixel

I would like to convert a PNG image to a 2 dimensional array where each array holds a list of the RGB values of that specific pixel. How could one create a program to read-in a *.png file and convert to this type of data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `PIL` installed then you can create an image with `Image.open` and get the colors like so:

```
data = [image.getpixel((x, y)) for x in range(image.width) for y in range(image.height)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing `pygame` module. Import a file into a `Surface` using `pygame.image.load`. You can then access the bit array from this using `pygame.surfarray.array2d`. Please see the Pygame docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wand`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/) for such basic tasks.  The syntax is very easy to read unlike other ImageMagik libs.  Basically you'd do something like:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

array = []
with Image(filename='yourfile.png') as img:
    array.append(img.channel_images)        # this is most likely wrong, but it should be something similar
```

It will be along those lines. Once I leave the office I will try this out.